# Has my CPU Intel Xeon E5-2650 integrated graphics?

Tags: cpu, gpu, graphics

I need to mod my GPU with a custom cooling-system, and wanted to know if I can simply run my PC without the GPU in it. **It seems like I should be searching for terms like "integrated graphics", "CPU graphics", "onboard graphics", etc. but I cannot seem to find this information.** The Intel ARK site doesn't include this information concerning my CPU either, so I am asking you.

Some additional info:
**Mobo:** Supermicro X9DAi
**CPU:** Intel Xeon E5-2650

Thank you!

Comment: This might be a odd question. But even if your CPU can handle some GPU tasks - if your mainboard doesn't provide a monitor connection (VGA, DVI, HDMI) how would you get the information to your monitor? And I haven't seen a mainboard with such a connector, but without graphics on board. So this question seems to be obsolete to me :-)

Comment: Anyway, the Xeon E5-2650 has no integrated graphics - what afaik no Xeon does have.

Comment: Ah, so even if my CPU would feature on-board graphics, it wouldn't be of any use with that mobo. Thank you!

Comment: For the time being, only the E3-1200 Family of Xeons have intergrated GPU (IRIS PRO): http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-e3-1200-hd-graphics-guide.html http://www.anandtech.com/show/9339/xeon-e31200-v4-launch-only-with-gpu-integrated

Answer (score 5):

No it does not. If a CPU has integrated graphics ARK will have a "Graphics Specifications" section for that CPU ([example](http://ark.intel.com/products/65523/Intel-Core-i7-3770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz)).

Comment: You stole my 10 rep points, *cry*